# Why is my send interest request not appearing? It's like the variables I defined are not working

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

ValueError at /HomeFeed/slug-1/detail/
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
interest_list = InterestList.objects.get(interestuser=account)

There are multiple errors in my code and this error is only one of them...

In my project, people get to post blog posts, and people that read the blog post and like it can send an "interest request" maybe to comment more about the blog post and the maker of the blog post can accept or reject that interest request. Its basically something like a friend request, except the request you are sending are your "thoughts" in a form. I am trying to tilt my code while building my relationship system to fit into this "submit interest system".

I have 4 models in total, one for the posts, one is my user account model, one is the interest list and the second one is the interestrequest.

There are 4 major functions, accept the request, decline the request (if you are the blog post maker) and send and unsend the request (if you are the interested user)

I find it difficult to link interest to blog post to account model such that the interest is sent to that particular blog post.

There are 5 things to note if you want to understand my code

- is_myself = True means you are looking at your own post
- is_others = True means you are looking at the accepted request's member's post (aka your interest has been accepted)
- is_others = False can mean 3 things

  1. Other people has sent a request to your post
  2. you have sent a request to other people's post
  3. no one has sent anything (which will be the default likely)

models.py

```
class InterestList(models.Model):
   interestuser = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interestuser")
   interests = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="interests") 

   def __str__(self):
      return self.interestuser.username

   def add_interest(self, account):

      if not account in self.interests.all():
         self.interests.add(account)
         self.save()

   def remove_interest(self, account):

      if account in self.interests.all():
         self.interests.remove(account)


class InterestRequest(models.Model):
   interestsender               = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interestsender")
   interestreceiver             = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="interestreceiver")
   is_active            = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
   timestamp        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   my_name           = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   my_thoughts         = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.interestsender.username
     
   def accept(self):
      receiver_interest_list = InterestList.objects.get(user=self.interestreceiver)
      if receiver_interest_list:
         receiver_interest_list.add_interest(self.interestsender)
         sender_interest_list = InterestList.objects.get(user=self.interestsender)
         if sender_interest_list:
            sender_interest_list.add_interest(self.interestreceiver)
            self.is_active = False
            self.save()

   def decline(self):
      self.is_active = False
      self.save()

   def cancel(self):
      self.is_active = False
      self.save()

class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False) 
 likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def detail_blog_view(request, slug):

    context = {}
#need to import a package get_object_or_404. return object or throw 404
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    total_likes = blog_post.total_likes()
    liked = False
    if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        liked = True
    context['liked'] = liked
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post
    context['total_likes'] = total_likes
    account = Account.objects.all()
    context['account'] = account

    try:
        interest_list = InterestList.objects.get(interestuser=account)
    except InterestList.DoesNotExist:
        interest_list = InterestList(interestuser=account)
        interest_list.save()
    interests = interest_list.interests.all()
    context['interests'] = interests

    is_myself = True
    is_others = False
    request_sent = InterestRequestStatus.NO_REQUEST_SENT.value
    interest_requests = None
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated and blog_post.author != user:
        is_myself = False
        if interests.filter(pk=user.id):
            is_others = True
        else:
            is_others = False
            #CASE 1: THEY HAVE SENT A REQUEST TO YOU
            if get_interest_request_or_false(sender=account, receiver=user) != False:
                request_sent = InterestRequestStatus.THEM_SENT_TO_YOU.value
                context['pending_interest_request_id'] = get_interest_request_or_false(sender=account, receiver=user).id #or you can use pk instead of id
            #CASE 2: REQUEST SENT FROM YOU TO THEM
            if get_interest_request_or_false(sender=account, receiver=user) != False:
                request_sent = InterestRequestStatus.YOU_SENT_TO_THEM.value
            #CASE 3: NTH HAS BEEN SENT
            else:
                request_sent = InterestRequestStatus.NO_REQUEST_SENT.value
   

    elif not user.is_authenticated:
        is_myself = False
    #when you are looking at your own post
    else:
        try:
            interest_requests = InterestRequest.objects.filter(receiver=user, is_active=True)
        except:
            pass

    context['is_myself'] = is_myself
    context['is_others'] = is_others
    context['request_sent'] = request_sent
    context['interest_requests'] = interest_requests
    context['BASE_URL'] = settings.BASE_URL

    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html', context)
```

utils.py

```
from HomeFeed.models import InterestRequest

def get_interest_request_or_false(interestsender, interestreceiver):
    try:
        return InterestRequest.objects.get(interestsender=interestsender, interestreceiver=interestreceiver, is_active=True)
    except InterestRequest.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

interest_request.py

```
from enum import Enum

class  InterestRequestStatus(Enum):
 NO_REQUEST_SENT = -1 #no request sent in that blog post to you or to them. this is the constant, how it should normally look like for most posts
 THEM_SENT_TO_YOU = 0
 YOU_SENT_TO_THEM = 1
```

template html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="d-flex flex-column mb-4" >

  <!-- THEM to YOU -->
  {% if request_sent == 0 %}
  <div class="card m-2 p-4" >
   <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
    <span class="friend-text align-items-center mr-2">Accept Member Request</span>
    <span id="id_cancel_{{id}}" class="decline-friend-request material-icons p-1" onclick='triggerDeclineFriendRequest("{{pending_friend_request_id}}")'>cancel</span>
      <span id="id_confirm_{{id}}" class="confirm-friend-request material-icons p-1" onclick='triggerAcceptFriendRequest("{{pending_friend_request_id}}")'>check</span>
   </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}




  <div class="card m-2 px-4 pb-4">
    <!-- Cancel Friend Request / Send Friend Request / Remove Friend -->
    {% if is_others == False and is_myself == False %}
      <!-- You sent them a request -->
      {% if request_sent == 1 %}
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center pt-4">
       <button class="btn btn-danger" id="id_cancel_friend_request_btn">
        Cancel Interest Request
       </button>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <!-- No requests have been sent -->
      {% if request_sent == -1 %}
      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center pt-4">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" id="id_send_friend_request_btn">
        Send Interest Request
       </button>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
   
  {% if is_others %}
   <div class="dropdown pt-4 m-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle friends-btn" type="button" id="id_friends_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Accepted Members
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" aria-labelledby="id_friends_toggle">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="removeFriend('{{id}}', onFriendRemoved)">Remove Member</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  {% endif %}


  {% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
  path('<slug>/detail/', detail_blog_view, name= "detail"),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

This error you described in the beginning is appearing because you are tryng to query a model using a `queryset`. In your **views.py** in your **detail_blog_view** you have a line that says:

```
account = Account.objects.all()
```

Here the value of the account variable is a `queryset` of ALL the available accounts, then you are trying to query your database using this queryset with a `get` method here:

```
interest_list = InterestList.objects.get(interestuser=account)
```

Since your `interestuser` field is a `one2one` relationship it can only accept a **single **object in the query while you are passing a `queryset`.

**THE SOLUTION**

All you have to do is instead of using `account = Account.objects.all()` write a query that would make the `account` variable store a single object value, for example:

1. `account = request.user # if you are logged in and trying to get your own account`
2. Pass a variable `pk` (of the user you want to get the list for) to the url path like this:

   ```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('detail_blog_view/<int:pk>/', views.detail_blog_view, name="detail_blog_view"),
    ]
   ```

then where you create links to your `detail_blog_view` pages write it something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'detail_blog_view' user.pk %}">{{ user.username }}</a> # here i'm passing a known user.pk from the context of the view that stores this template.
```

and in the end in your view query your `account` with the `pk` passed in the `url` like this:

```
account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Comment: Hi my saviour! can i not add anything new into my url?

Comment: because as you can see from my url.py i already have slug in my url. basically all my urls related to the posts have a slug, so if i change it to pk instead i will have to learn how to requery my data and as you know, I am very bad at this haha..

Comment: Yes but that slug is for a blog post link brother, you are trying to query a single `Account` object so you will HAVE to use some of variable to query it and the only way to get that variable is from the `GET` request in your url, so you either have to pass an `Account` object pk or use the `request.user` to query your account

Comment: Alternatively you can add a relationship to the `Account` model in your `BlogPost` model so you could get all the interest objects for the post using something like this: `account = blog_post.account`

Comment: haha im sorry bro i think you lost me because i know you are correct but I quite dont understand what you mean and how to change my code sorry! How about a 5 min chatroom session HAHHAHA

Comment: currently i tried to only change to account = request.user and got `TypeError at /HomeFeed/slug-40-9-0/detail/
'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`

Comment: Hi bro i have added an author field in my blopost model which is a foreign key to the account model

Comment: that is because you are not logged in, log in an account and try again, as about the chat session I'm not sure how to start one unless theres a bunch of comments here :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226866/discussion-between-joowon-and-sldem).